# My iphone 4 needs a software update but none show up?

Tags: iphone

My Iphone 4 needs a software update when I try to download an app but when I go to settings it says there are none. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your only chance is if there is an older version of the app that will run on iOS 7.1.2, which is the last iOS available for iPhone 4. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225206/can-an-iphone-4-be-updated-to-ios-9?rq=1 & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115812/latest-compatible-version-of-an-app/115813#115813

Answer (score 1):

The last version of iOS that the iPhone 4 supports is iOS 7.1.2. You will not find any more software updates for the iPhone 4 beyond this and you are unable to install any apps that require a more recent version of iOS.